# save selection in session and show in table

Tags: php, html, session, selector

I have a selector that selects all the data from my database.

```
<?php
        $results = $database->Selector();
?>
        <form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>
            <select name='train_id[]' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>
            <?php
                foreach($results as $train_details){ //Look through every result in DB
                        echo "<option value=" . $train_details['train_id'] . ">" . $train_details['train_name'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select><br />
            <td>
                <input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add to list'/>
            </td>
        </form>
<?php
    include 'train_selector_result.php'; //This will display the results (will show page later)
```

And the '*`train_selector_result.php`*' page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['train_id'])){
//Table stuff here (Won't place here because too long)
//And then the table results:
    foreach ($_POST['train_id'] as $selectedOption){
        $test = $database->testingSelector($selectedOption);
                    foreach($test as $lol){
                ?>
                <tr> 
                    <td name="train_name"><?= $lol['train_name']?></td>
                    <td><?= $lol['number_of_bogies']?></td>
                    <td><?= $lol['number_of_axles']?></td>
                    <td><a href="expand_info.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">More Information</a></td>
                    <td><a href="train_model.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">Model</a></td> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?= $lol['train_id']?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
    }
}
```

The functions:

```
function testingSelector($selectedOption){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_id", $selectedOption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }

function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_name, train_id FROM train_information ORDER BY train_name";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

This is all working well. When i select multiple items from the selector and press the Submit button, it will show me those selected items.

However, i don't want them to disappear whenever i add an other one or go to the home screen. So i would like to put them in a session.

I tryed to put them in a session but it did not work. (Got undifind Index Errors).
How i did it:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['train_id'])){
//Table stuff here (Won't place here because too long)
//And then the table results:
    foreach ($_POST['train_id'] as $selectedOption){
        $test = $database->testingSelector($selectedOption);
        $_SESSION['selector'] = $test
                    foreach($_SESSION['selector'] as $lol){
                ?>
                <tr> 
                    <td name="train_name"><?= $lol['train_name']?></td>
                    <td><?= $lol['number_of_bogies']?></td>
                    <td><?= $lol['number_of_axles']?></td>
                    <td><a href="expand_info.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">More Information</a></td>
                    <td><a href="train_model.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">Model</a></td> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?= $lol['train_id']?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
    }
}
```

However this did not work... (Already started a session, because i'm logged in!)

**EDIT:**

What it looks when i select 3 trains and press submit:

[image: What it looks]

And when i add 1 more, it looks like this:

[image: What it looks when i add 1 more]

As you can see, the table gets resetted. While i actually want it to add 1 extra column!

Comment: add `action` attribute in your `<form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>` tag so it goes to the page where it is supposed to give it a value to the session.

Comment: But i don't want that. because the selector is on the homepage, and i want to see the results on the homepage.

Comment: Okay, I think I understood. Do you have somewhere in your homepage where it does check if the user has checked/clicked a `selector` so it adds to the `SESSION` ?

Comment: I have index.php. and there i require the selector (the top code). There i check what the user clicks etc. And then when he presses Submit. a table under the selector gets created with the just checked details.

Comment: Where is your `javascript` code?

Comment: I made an edit @holpducki

Comment: Ah yes, so in your `javascript` where you add the `trains` to the table, you should use something to add, not to change the whole table content. And still inside that `javascript` you should call a `PHP` file sending the trains informations to add to a `SESSION` so it gets saved. Can you please post you `javascript` code?

Comment: I don't have javascript code, and also when i add a item. It gets inserted in the database. And the selector reads everything what is inside the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80048/discussion-between-holpducki-and-mitch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As we discussed in chat:*

in your `train_selector_result.php` page change to this

```
foreach ($_POST['train_id'] as $selectedOption){
    //if has selected selector, then add to session 
    $test = $database->testingSelector($selectedOption); 
    $_SESSION["selector"][] = $test; 
} 

foreach ($_SESSION["selector"] as $result){
    $lol = $result[0];
    ?> 
    <tr> 
    <td name="train_name"><?= $lol['train_name']?></td> 
    <td><?= $lol['number_of_bogies']?></td> 
    <td><?= $lol['number_of_axles']?></td> 
    <td><a href="expand_info.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">More Information</a></td> 
    <td><a href="train_model.php?train_id=<?= $lol['train_id']?>">Model</a></td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?= $lol['train_id']?>"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me good!

Comment: We are here to help! :D